# Reordering an array in a customized way

Tags: c#, .net, list, split

I have an array of items that prints to pdf in the following order. 
Lets say for eg:

```
lines = {1, 2, 3, 
         4, 5, 6, 
         7, 8, 9, 
         10}
```

is the content of my array.

However I want to change the order of the items in the array to

```
  {1, 4, 7,
   2, 5, 8, 
   3, 6, 9, 
   10}
```

Then I pass this array to my print engine. Basically if there are more than 3 items in the array, my new code should reorder it.

Could somebody help me figuring out the logic for that.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you basically want to take a two dimensional array and transpose rows and columns. Is that correct?

Comment: I think it is a one-D array, but he wants to treat it like a 2-D array and transpose it, resulting in another one-D array with the same elements in a different order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order the lines by the modulus of the line index with the number of rows.

```
public static ICollection<T> Sort<T>(ICollection<T> lines, int columns)
{
    var rows = lines.Count/columns;
    if (rows == 0)
    {
        return lines;
    }
    return lines.Select((line, i) => new {line, i})
                .OrderBy(item => item.i < columns*rows ? item.i%rows : rows)
                .Select(item => item.line)
                .ToList();
}
```

**Edit:** Alternatively you can use an iterator method and the list's indexer instead of LINQ:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IList<T> lines, int columns)
{
    var rows = lines.Count/columns;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        var index = rows > 0 && i < columns*rows
            ? (i%columns)*rows + i/columns
            : i;
        yield return lines[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. You don't even need `IList<T>` for this code `IEnumerable<T>` would be enough. With `IList<T>` you can remove "zip"/sort portion (first select) and instead just pick items by final position.

Comment: Side note: please consider editing your answer to inline what exact question you are answering.

Comment: I generally don't like using IEnumerable if I need to know the number of elements up front. Why do I need to restate the question in my answer?

Comment: It's optional suggestion - it is not very clear what OP wants (i.e. see how I understood it) and 2 other comments trying to figure out the question. You probably correct in your understanding, but for future readers it would be beneficial to quickly see what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "for linear array assuming every 9 elements form 3x3 matrix transpose each subsequence, keep remainder as-is":

```
// assuming T[] items;
var toTranspose = (items.Count() / 9) * 9;
var remap = new int[]{1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9 };

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, toTranspose)
  .Select(pos => items[(pos / 9) * 9 + (remap[pos % 9] - 1)])
  .Concat(items.Skip(toTranspose)
  .ToArray();
```

Summary of code:

- get number of items that need to be moved (which is number of groups of 9 items `int numberOfGroup = Count()/9;`, multiplied by group size)
- have custom transformation in `remap` array (note that indexes copied as-is from sample and actually off-by-one hence `-1` in computing index)
- for each element index under  `toTranspose` get source element from corresponding group and apply transformation with `remap`.
- finally `Concat` the remainder.

Notes:

- one can easily provide custom transformation or inline transposition if needed.
- can't apply transformation to the last partial group as elements will have to go to non-existent positions.

Comment: Why do you need `var toTranspose = (items.Count() / 9) * 9;` - this is basically just `items.Count()`?

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee `(10/9)*9 != 10` :)